# TLF TextField not working on IOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, tlf

I am using Air 14.0.In Flash Professional CS6.I checked this on iPad.My app contains some external swf's.Actually IOS doesn't allow external swf's data.for this i hosted external swf's on remote server.But that external swf's library movieclips contains some tlf textfields. Movieclips which contains tlfTexts that movieclips not accessing from library in IOS.